# access to an array which a key issued from a function result in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have a $period var which is defined with :

```
Array
(
[2012-03-09] => Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [group] => 1
                [color] => #00FF00
            )

    )

[2012-03-07] => Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [group] => 2
                [color] => #00FF00
            )

    )
)
```

I use smarty, and I want to print the value if the key exist and then iterate on all data :

```
{if array_key_exists($jour->nameMysql(), $periods)}
    {foreach from=$periods[$jour->nameMysql()] item=periodsdf}
        {$periodsdf}
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

The key is returned by the result of a function *$jour->nameMysql()*. the first part of the code is working (array_key_exists but the foreach doesn't function. it hangs and I've not error message or warning

I already tryied to change the foreach by *{foreach from="$periods.{$jour->nameMysql()}" item=periodsdf}* but it doesn't work.

I also tryied to assign the $jour->nameMysql() to a var and use that var but it doesn't work

can you help me to make it work ?

**Edit**

This code give the result I want

```
{php}
   $periods = $this->get_template_vars('periods');
   $jour = $this->get_template_vars('jour');
   $this->assign('period', $periods[$jour->nameMysql()]);
{/php}
{foreach from=$period item=per}
   <div style='color: {$per.color}'>{$per.group}</div>
{/foreach}
```

If I find the smarty syntax ... it's good

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
{$key = $jour->nameMysql()}
{if array_key_exists($key, $periods)}
    {foreach from=$periods.$key item=periodsdf}
        {$periodsdf}
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

or

```
{if isset($periods.$key)}
    {foreach from=$periods.$key item=periodsdf}
        {$periodsdf}
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Comment: I don't know why but after {$key = $jour->nameMysql()} ... {$key} return nothing